# React Button with link and onSubmit doesn't execute both

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

this is my first question here, so be kind, I'm pretty new..

I have a React component where I have a button. This button contains a link and calls a onSubmit function doeing an API call. So I want to do an API call while redirecting the user to the homepage.

My problem now is, that always only the API call or the redirect is executed but never both.

I've already tried to use the href property itself, to use React Link component and to use window.location.onClick but nothing is working.

This is my component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from "react";
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import './route.css';
import DataServer from "../api/DataServer";
import { AppContext } from "../context/AppContext";





const Register = () => {

  const {logged, setLogged} = useContext(AppContext);
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    useremail: "",
    userpassword: "",
    username: "",
    userlastname: "",
    userprename: "",
    userdescription: "",
    userbirthdate: "",
  });
  
  const { useremail, userpassword, username, userlastname, userprename, userdescription, userbirthdate } = inputs;
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);
    
  const onChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setInputs({ ...inputs, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
    
  function validEmail(useremail) {
    return /^[a-zA-Z]{4}\d{4}@stud.hs-kl.de/.test(useremail);
  }

  const onSubmitForm = async e => {
    
    if(!validEmail(useremail)){
      console.log("WARNUNG hinzufügen");
    }
    else{
    
    try {      
      const response = await DataServer.post("/authentication/register", {
        useremail: useremail,
        userpassword: userpassword,
        username: username,
        userlastname: userlastname,
        userprename: userprename,
        userdescription: userdescription,
        userbirthdate: userbirthdate,
      })


      const parseRes = await response.json();

      if (parseRes.jwtToken) {
        localStorage.setItem("token", parseRes.jwtToken);
        setLogged(true);
      } else {
        setLogged(false);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  }
}


    useEffect(()=>{

      if(validEmail(useremail)){
        setValidated(true);
      }
      else{
        setValidated(false);
      }
    
    },[useremail])
 
    return (
      <Container className="routeContainer">
          <h1>Registriere dich!</h1>
       <Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
          <Form.Row>
            <Form.Group  controlId="Useremail">
              <Form.Label>E-Mail Adresse</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control 
                className="is-invalid"
                required
                type="email" 
                name="useremail"
                placeholder="test0001@stud.hs-kl.de" 
                value={useremail}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              />
            <Form.Text id="passwordHelpBlock" muted>
          Text
        </Form.Text>
        {validated === false ?
        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">Gib die richtige E-mail ein</Form.Control.Feedback>
          }
            
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group  controlId="Userpassword">
              <Form.Label htmlFor="inputPassword5">Passwort</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control 
                required
                type="password" 
                name="userpassword"
                id = " inputPassword5 "
                placeholder="Passwort"
                aria-descriptionby = "passwordHelpBlock"
                value={userpassword}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              />
              <Form.Text id = " inputPassword5 " muted>Dein Passwort muss zwischen 8 und 20 Zeilen sein.</Form.Text>
               <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
              Du musst ein Passwort eingeben
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form.Row>
            <Form.Group controlId="UserLastname">
              <Form.Label>Nachname</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control 
                required
                placeholder="Mustermann" 
                name="userlastname"
                value={userlastname}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                />
                <Form.Control.Feedback>Sieht gut aus!</Form.Control.Feedback>
               <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
              Du musst ein Nachnamen eingeben
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId="UserPrename">
              <Form.Label>Vorname</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control 
                required
                placeholder="Max" 
                name="userprename"
                value={userprename}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                />
               <Form.Control.Feedback>Sieht gut aus!</Form.Control.Feedback>
               <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
              Du musst ein Vornamen eingeben
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId="username">
              <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control 
                required
                placeholder="Username" 
                name="username"
                value={username}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                />
                <Form.Control.Feedback>Sieht gut aus!</Form.Control.Feedback>
               <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
              Du musst ein Usernamen eingeben
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId="UserBirthdate">
              <Form.Label>Geburtsdatum</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                required
                type="date"
                name="userbirthdate"
                value={userbirthdate}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                />
              <Form.Control.Feedback>Sieht gut aus!</Form.Control.Feedback>
               <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
              Du musst ein Geburtsdatum eingeben
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId="UserDescription">
              <Form.Label>Über Mich</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control 
              as="textarea" 
              rows={3} 
              name="userdescription"
              value={userdescription}
              onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.File 
                id="UserImage" 
                label="Profilbild" 
                name="userimage"
              />
            </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group id="formGridCheckbox">
            <Form.Row>
            
              <Form.Check
                required
                type="checkbox" 
                label="Datenschutzbestimmungen" 
                name="dataprivacy"
                > 
                </Form.Check> 
                <a className="link" href="./Cookiepolicy"> siehe hier.</a>
              </Form.Row>
              <Form.Control.Feedback>Sieht gut aus!</Form.Control.Feedback>
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
             Du musst die Datenschutzbestimmungen akzeptieren
           </Form.Control.Feedback>
          </Form.Group>

 
    <div className="buttonBackground" >
        <Button href="/" type="submit" className="button">Registrieren</Button>
    </div>     
</Form>
      </Container>
  
    );
  };
  
  export default Register;
```

As mentioned in the comments I updated my onSubmit function to the following, but with no success:

```
const onSubmitForm = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("onSubmitForm in Register ausgeführt");
    
    if(!validEmail(useremail)){
      console.log("WARNUNG hinzufügen");
    } else{
    try {      
      const response = await DataServer.post("/authentication/register", {
        useremail: useremail,
        userpassword: userpassword,
        username: username,
        userlastname: userlastname,
        userprename: userprename,
        userdescription: userdescription,
        userbirthdate: userbirthdate,
      })

      const parseRes = await response.json();
      if (parseRes.jwtToken) {
        localStorage.setItem("token", parseRes.jwtToken);
        setLogged(true);
        console.log("Registrierung erfolgreich");
      } else {
        setLogged(false);
        console.log(parseRes);
      }
      history.push("/home");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: You likely don't want to do direct location manipulation as this will reload your app, which may have unintentional side-effects. You should instead implement app navigation (react-router-dom, or react-navigation, etc..). I notice you also are not preventing the default form action from occurring when submitting.

Comment: You need to do `e.preventDefault()` first, to prevent the browser from submitting the form the regular way. Next, await your ajax call, as you already do. At the end, run the redirection command, whether a hard `location = "/";` or otherwise.

Comment: It seems I do not get the point with preventDefault(), I added it to my onSubmit function and also used history.push("/"), but that didn't work as well.

Comment: You also need to remove the `href="/"` from the `Button`

Comment: Other than a likely "Cannot update state of unmounted..." type error after navigation occurs, what isn't working? You've a few things the submit handler is doing... are they *all* not working? Or something more specific?

Comment: @DrewReese If I have any kind of link or redirect the API call isn't working anymore, so no data is written to the database. If I delete every kind of link from the code, the API call is executed and data is written to the database. Everyting else is working as expected.

Comment: Is your code failing at the email validation? Is it failing at the POST request? Failing at parsing the JSON response? Failing at setting localStorage? State update? History PUSH? Did you ensure you removed all other "link"-ish/href/URL stuff from the button so it's ***only*** submitting the form?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do first a action and then the other one.

Inside the onSubmitForm function, on the final of the try block, put: window.location.href = "/"

```
 if (parseRes.jwtToken) {
    localStorage.setItem("token", parseRes.jwtToken);
    setLogged(true);
  } else {
    setLogged(false);
  }
  window.location.href = "/"
```

Comment: Following the idea from @david-vargas, try to use the `useHistory` hook from React Router and delete the `href` property from your `<Button ... />` component.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've already tried that, but this does not work for me. I know that the issue must have to do something with async behavior but I do not know how to solve it..

Comment: I've also aplied your advice @rigojr , but unfortunatly this worked neither

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const onSubmitForm = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!validEmail(useremail)){
    console.log("WARNUNG hinzufügen");
  } else {
    DataServer.post("/authentication/register", {
      //...
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(parseRes => {
      if (parseRes.jwtToken) {
        localStorage.setItem("token", parseRes.jwtToken);
        setLogged(true);
      } else {
        setLogged(false);
      }
    window.location.href = "/"
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

Comment: this throws response.json() is not a function error

Comment: @DennisPyka do you have your code updated ? There are no chance to have it in a sandbox or any live coding tool in order to debugging ?